# css flexbox break parent by screen width

Tags: css, flexbox

if got something like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/screen.css?v=737285430" media="screen, projection" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="articlesShorten">
            <article class="articleShorten">
                text1
            </article>
            <article class="articleShorten">
                text2
            </article>
            <article class="articleShorten">
                text3
            </article>
            <article class="articleShorten">
                text4
            </article>
            <article class="articleShorten">
                text5
            </article>
            <article class="articleShorten">
                text6
            </article>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#articlesShorten {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;

  display: -moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;

  display: box;
  box-orient: horizontal;
}

.articleShorten {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  box-flex: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .articleShorten {
    width: 30%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 999px) {
  .articleShorten {
    width: 40%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 599px) {
  .articleShorten {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

I want to show the articles for little screens like this:

text1

text2

text3

...

for wider one like this:

text1 | text2

text3 | text4

...

and for the rest like this:

text1 | text2 | text3

text4 | text5 | text6

but all I'm able to get is something like this:

text1 | text2 | text3 | text4 | text5 | text6 | ...

is it possible to do this ONLY in CSS3? I don't want to check the width in my PHP which generates the HTML and add every x article a new row. I just want that the flexbox (parent?) break at screen width and make a new row. Therefore I tried to give the childboxes different widths of the screen width.

**EDIT:** correct CSS Syntax
The articles could have different height!!

Comment: Alot of you code is not correct, like the box-orient you use and the display box. Check out http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/responsive-design-of-the-future-with-flexbox to see how to do what you are looking for

Comment: @PeteD The code is not *wrong*, it just uses properties from the deprecated 2009 Flexbox draft.  That in itself is not wrong, but the portion the OP needs (wrapping) exists in the specification but does not exist in any browser's 2009 implementation.  Otherwise, the only *wrongness* here is using these properties without including the standard ones.

Comment: @cimmanon Thanks for the info about the deprecated code. I only looked up the flexbox recently so I didn't know that it existed and was deprecated in 2009.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that you're using the deprecated 2009 Flexbox properties, there are 2 things missing in your example: wrapping and flex-basis.  Wrapping doesn't exist in any browser's 2009 implementation and flex-basis doesn't exist at all in that draft.

Using media queries to define the widths of the flex elements is highly unnecessary, let the content determine where it should be wrapping.  Be aware that this will only work in Chrome, Opera, and IE10 (Firefox will support it *soon*):

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/BjtxL

```
#articlesShorten {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.articleShorten {
  -webkit-flex: 1 20em;
  -ms-flex: 1 20em;
  flex: 1 20em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

If the columns should be uniform, using the multicolumn module might be a better way to go, and it has better browser support:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/rnmqwlst

```
#articlesShorten {
  -webkit-columns: 10em;
  -moz-columns: 10em;
  columns: 10em;
}
```

Comment: I'm developing an android app, my real problem is the "browser" of the webView in android. e.g. I've got a nexus 7 (7inch (17,78 cm), 1280 x 800 px, 216 ppi) and I want to show 2 columns in portrait and 3 in landscape. If it's open on a mobile phone (like my nexus S) I want to show only 1 column. The article itself are very different of width (there a lot of text inside, without break inside), therefore I made the media queries. How could I manipulate your (first) solution to have this? In the moment there's only 1 column (very thin and long articles, but I want them like a square) everywhere.

Comment: oh, and it wasn't in my mind to use deprecated properties, it's my first use of flexbox and I found the code in a (deprecated) tutorial...

Comment: Just because it's deprecated doesn't mean it *shouldn't* be used, you use what you have to for the browsers you need to support.  Other than Blackberry 10 ([caniuse says iOS7 will support the standard Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)), pretty much every other mobile browser only has the 2009 implementation of Flexbox, so you're stuck there:  none of those browsers support wrapping because there's no implementation for `box-lines: multiple`.