# CSS Flexbox and Responsive Design: Converting 3 columns into 2 rows

Tags: css, responsive-design, flexbox

I'm somewhat new to flexbox.  I want to be able to take a three column layout and turn those three columns into two rows when they hit a smaller width in the browser.

For example:

```
Container
Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3
```

turns into:

```
Container
Col 1 | Col 3
Col 2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [css flexbox break parent by screen width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290107/css-flexbox-break-parent-by-screen-width)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it, although it isn't very 'clean' per se.

Use a media query to change the flex-basis of the columns. So at a narrow width, the flex-basis would be %50, at a wide width, 33%.

Then use order to arrange the boxes as you wish.

Check it out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LvIni