# Media query javascript manipulation

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I have a grid, that is being laid out with media queries, media query is altering the size of the `article` tag, which alters the number of columns. (`grid_item`s are of fixed size)

```
<section id="grid">
        <article>
            <div class="grid_item">
            </div>
            <div class="grid_item">
            </div>
            <div class="grid_item">
            </div>
            <div class="grid_item">
            </div>
       </article>
</section>
```

Example media query (delivers a 5 column grid)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1313px)
{
    #grid article
    {
        width: 1034px * $grid_scale;
     }
}
```

But what I wish to do now, is to allow the user to set the number of columns.

How would I go about doing that?

I was hoping to simply set the `article`'s width to what the breakpoints set them at, but that didn't work. (Using a predefined map of `[NumberOfColumns, ArticleWidth]`)

(I am using scss/sass)

**EDIT**
Question Rephrase
Currently number of columns is dependant on viewport width, but I also want the option to set the number of columns. So that even if there is space for 5, only show 3.

Comment: As a side not you might want to look at something like http://susy.oddbird.net/ for a complete dyanmic grid solution.

Comment: What is the value of $grid_scale?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem here is.  If you're hoping to magically do this via Sass, you're out of luck because Sass is a compiled language.  You would have to generate all possible permeations in advance.

Comment: @Rupert ah that was a bit of extra code I forgot to remove. My scss is alot more complicated than what is above.

Comment: @cimmanon How do I go about generating all possible permeations. Currently the grid wraps to create the second row. (Contents fixed size, so parent size controls the wrap). I can write each, but I am trying to figure out how to write it efficiently in scss.

Comment: Again, it's not clear what you actually want.  I have no idea what you're actually trying to do.  Do you know what CSS you want generated?  What does any of this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: I thought js could be used to do some kind of class swapping. But i am hoping it is possible to do a css query not based on viewport but on parent width. Is that possible.

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with Sass at all then?  Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290107/css-flexbox-break-parent-by-screen-width